# Sharepoint Search Rest API not returning search results from Onedrive/personal sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-search, mysite, onedrive

Our goal is to query the Sharepoint Search API and fetch all files from OneDrive (my drives/personal sites) where the search input exists in the content.
We are using the following query:

```
POST https://[tenantName].sharepoint.com/_api/search/postquery 
Body: { "request": { "Querytext": "abc", "RefinementFilters": [ "Path:\"https://[tenantName]-my.sharepoint.com/personal*\"" ] } }
```

But no results are being returned, when we remove the `RefinementFilters`, search api is returning responses from sharepoint sites, but we want search on Onedrive only. we have added all the permissions required, to use this api (mentioned here : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/vesku/using-add-in-only-app-only-permissions-with-search-queries-in-sharepoint-online).

Are we missing any anything here? is there special configuration required for onedrive? Any help  will be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: I cannot test the syntax but I believe you missed `refiners='Path'` part

Answer (score 0):

Your query require `Refiners` parameters to match with `RefinementFilters`:

```
Body: { "request": { "Querytext": "abc", 
"Refiners":"Path",
"RefinementFilters": [ "Path:\"https://[tenantName]-my.sharepoint.com/personal*\"" ] } }
```

Comment: It didn't work, actually none of the Onedrive(my site) files are being returned Even If I remove the  the RefinementFilters, the response does not returns the onedrive files where this text exist, it ONLY returns the other sharepoint site's files.

Comment: @ShahtajK do you get any Onedrive file result using the existing search box?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to search on OneDrive from UI, but not via this search api. I have added the required tenant level permission on this application, is there any other permission required to access it?

Comment: I tested with PowerShell query my SPO site and it works. I think you got problem on other parts, not the query.

Comment: Yes, as I'm able to get responses from sharepoint sites with the same query (after removing filters), but can you please check the permissions and tell me if these xml permission is enough to run this query for one drive ? do we need any other permission to search on onedrive ?

Comment: I am using default setup for my OneDrive. The library's Advanced settings "Allow items from this document library to appear in search results?" is YES. Regarding the permission I don't think we are allowed to change the library's permission. We can change individual files only.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the change you're talking about for individual files? What are those permissions? and they are not applied on default Onedrive setup? so basically you're suggesting that their are some special settings enabled on my account which is blocking the access? which is turned off by default ?

Comment: By clicking "..." on your file or folder > Manage access > in the right panel click "Advanced" > Stop Inheriting Permission. Then remove yourself. It is unlikely happen.